# Integrating Matomo (Piwik) tracking to Confluence

Tags: google-analytics, confluence, matomo

We are using in-premise version of confluence but still do not have insights to the confluence code but would like to track page views, actions, users etc using Matomo  (https://matomo.org/) or Google Analytics.

To enable any kind of tracking, we atleast need to paste a few lines of JS code to index.html.

But in case of confluence, since we do not have access to the code, how we can make this work.

Can anyone please help here.

Answer (score 2):

You may want to check using a [Piwik Add-on from the Atlassian Marketplace](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/search?query=piwik).

The [smartics Piwik Integration](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/apps/1214083/smartics-integration-for-piwik?hosting=server&tab=overview) is one option.

Documentation on how to configure this add-on is found at the [add-on's homepage](https://www.smartics.eu/confluence/x/4ID-AQ).

Biased alert: Please note that I am one of the developers of the add-on. ;)

Comment: Does that still work in 2021 with new Matomo versions?